# Is int[] is a object?

Tags: arrays, jvm, int

> Suppose int[] a = new int[]; It will create a new object or not ? 
>   and one more question . 
>   if int[] a = { 1 , 4 , 5 , 6 } Here it will create a new object or not ? if it's creating a >new object then how it will be created

Comment: Hard to say, since you don't say what language you're using.  (The JVM supports several languages.)

Comment: Why don't you try running `int[] a = new int[];` and seeing what happens. `int[] a = {1, 2, 4, 5, 6};` will make an array of integers

Comment: But just in case you happen to be dealing with Java:  Yes, all arrays are objects, and they have a (system-created) Class just like any other object.

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about Java then the answer is Yes it will create a new object

The Java Language Specification section 4.3.1 clearly says that:

> **An object is a class instance or an array.**

---

Also,

> In the Java programming language arrays are objects (§4.3.1), are
>   dynamically created, and may be assigned to variables of type Object
>   (§4.3.2). All methods of class Object may be invoked on an array.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are object only. Arrays is the object that holds references of primitive or object

Comment: Actually, an array is an object that holds either primitives or references to objects.  In Java there is no such thing as a reference to a primitive.

Answer (score 1):

Java Arrays are Object(s) with syntatical sugar.

```
int [] a = new int[2];
a[0] = 1;
a[1] = 2;
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
```

You can also declare the array

```
int [] a = {1,2};
```

Regardless of how you declare the array, it is an Object. Is has a length field, additionally you can cast it to an Object,

```
int[] a = { 1, 2 };
Object o = a;
System.out.println(o.getClass().getName());
```

It does output the unfortunately named,

```
[I
```

You can use the [`Array`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html) utility from the reflect package,

```
System.out.println(Array.get(a, 0));
```

From the [`Array`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html) Javadoc,

> The `Array` class provides static methods to dynamically create and access Java arrays.